# How can I test my C++ program on various platforms?

Tags: c++

What would be a practical way to test a C++ program on various platforms? Even within an operating system, I would like to test it on different versions (e.g., OS X 10.7, 10.8, 10.9, etc). I have access to a handful of machines that run on either Windows, Linux, or Mac OS X, but have a specific version installed. Assume I can compile the program on that platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create virtual machines (VirtualBox, VMWare Player) for those systems and different versions.

Of course this may depend on specific hardware requested by your software.

Comment: The downside to this is that I would need to have the various platforms with me. Do you know if there's an online service that would allow me to test-run my program on various platforms? I looked into Amazon cloud services, but they didn't support Mac OS X.

Comment: Well, if you don't want it to host yourself I would've recommended Amazon services. For Mac OS X you may find http://xcloud.me useful. But I don't have any experience with it.